# Weird warning when debuging electron on VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

When debugging my electron app on VSCode, I have this warning:

```
Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/dodo/Desktop/News/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js: ENOENT, main.js.map not found in c:\Users\dodo\Desktop\News\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar
```

Now this does not prevent the app from starting, but it is worrying me, and so far I could not find the cause of this warning.
Besides, **default_app.asar** is a file, not a directory.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {  
    "electron": "^10.1.5",  
    "growl": "^1.10.5",  
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",  
    "jsdom": "^16.2.2",  
    "node-notifier": "7.0.1",  
    "slug": "^3.3.4",  
    "sync-request": "6.1.0"  
}
```

**launch.json** configuration

```
{
    "name": "Electron: Main",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "node",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app/main.js",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
    "runtimeArgs": ["--remote-debugging-port=9223", "."],
    "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
    },
}
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102042#issuecomment-656402933

Comment: this does the trick, thanks !